# Komal `re` and Sharp `Re` sound Identical [Bansuri]

Tags: practice, indian-classical, bansuri

I'm using the fingering chart below for Bansuri

I know it takes time to master half-notes. A lot of times sound doesn't come, which is fine. But at least I can distinguish the Komal notes of `dha`, `ni`, `ga`, `Ma` from the Sharp notes of  `Dha`, `Ni`, `Ga`, `Ma`

But what about `re`?

Whether I attempt to play Komal `re` or Sharp `Re` it sounds the same.

Any best practices for overcoming this?

As a beginner (two months, can practice up to an hour daily, 5 to 6 times a week), I'd rather get a strong foundation and practice using this complex fingering chart. Plus it makes intuitive sense (to me).

[image: Bansuri fingering chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell you that without practice it's not going to be easy. I could remind myself of the same situation. First, I would like to recommend that you should get familiar with the sound frequency of all of the notation unless you clearly can't differentiate the sound of which note or sur had been played. You would probably get more confused, so you may bring the keyboard instrument for that.

Or you could listen to the song with having notation of that song. 
For playing those two notes there are only minor differences of blow and if the third finger hole (from the top position of flute) will slightly open/close (not necessarily half) than still. You may listen to Komal `re` (if the first three whole blocking sound is `sa` for you). 
It was a challenge for me to block that hole entirely rather than half open.

I would like to add that if you begin saptak from all holes blocked as `sa` then it will be easier to play these notes.

If you don't have a keyboard, and the song you may play is composed within Bhairav, Poorvi, Marwa, (which have komal re) or [raga asavari](http://tanarang.com/english/komal-rishabh-asawari_eng.htm) (this has both `re`'s)
You can also search on YouTube to find the composition of this raag.

So keep practicing! If you do, you will surely get success. Hope my answer helps. All the best.

Comment: Hello @nisarg-desai `so you may bring the keyboard instrument for that.` How would I bring a keyboard instrument for that. I only have access to Bansuri. `or may listen the song with having notation of that song. ` Can you add links to songs with these notations

Comment: you may use mobile app if you don't have keyboard. and song you may play that composed within  Bhairav, Poorvi, Marwa `that` that have shudhdh `re` and here is raga asavari http://www.tanarang.com/english/komal-rishabh-asawari_eng.htm both re included. but proceed only once you able to differentiate them on sound level.

Comment: Thank you so much .... such a helpful link ... I marked your solution as answer. If possible please include link in your original answer (to help other Bansuri students)

Comment: @Marium happy to help. answer has been updated.

Comment: @NisargDesai Bhairav, Purvi, Marwa use "komal re", not shuddh re.. need to edit that part!

Comment: oh yes @dryleaf, thanks for noted that. i intense-fully mentioned them by having komal `re` in mind but mistakenly wrote shudhdh. make it correct.